# Troubles in connecting to database on Wildfly using postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly

I'm having trouble connecting to database on Wildfly using postgresql and I write in Red Hat Core Studio.
My standalone.xml is:

```
<datasources>
         <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
         <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
              <driver>h2</driver>
              <security>
                   <user-name>sa</user-name>
                   <password>sa</password>
              </security>
          </datasource>
          <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/tvTutorial" pool-name="tvTutorial" enabled="true" statistics-enabled="true">
               <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql//localhost:5432/tvTutorial</connection-url>
               <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
               <connection-property name="url">
                   jdbc:postgresql//localhost:5432/tvTutorial
               </connection-property>
               <driver>NewPestsList-1.0.war</driver>
               <security>
                   <user-name>user</user-name>
                   <password>password</password>
               </security>
           <validation>
               <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                   <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                   <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
            </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
...
    </deployment>
    </deployments>
</server>
```

My persistence.xml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="NewPestsList">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.driver'
                value='org.postgresql.Driver' />
            <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.url'
                value='jdbc:postgresql//localhost:5432/tvTutorial' />
            <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.user'
                value='user' />
            <property name='javax.persistence.jdbc.password'
                value='password' />
            <property name='hibernate.dialect'
                value='org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect' />
            <property name='hibernate.connection.shutdown' value='true' />
            <property name='hibernate.show_sql' value='false' />
            <property name='hibernate.format_sql' value='false' />
            <property name="hibernate.case.use_query_cache"
                value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I go in wildfly HAL management

`console/configuration/subsystems/datasources&drivers/JDBC Drivers/`

I see two JDBC drivers:

`"NewPestsList-1.0.war"` and `"NewPestsList-1.0.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2"`
as in picture
[two war files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK7dG.png)
My log is:

```
16:10:55,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/tvTutorial]
16:10:55,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = NewPestsList-1.0.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2
16:10:55,950 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/NewPestsList-1.0' from server 'default-server'
16:10:55,951 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = NewPestsList-1.0.war
16:10:55,995 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'NewPestsList-1.0.war#NewPestsList'
16:10:55,998 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@1145c435
16:10:55,999 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'NewPestsList-1.0.war#NewPestsList'
16:10:56,054 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment NewPestsList-1.0.war (runtime-name: NewPestsList-1.0.war) in 105ms
16:10:56,054 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("composite") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0441: Operation has resulted in failed or missing services 
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.NewPestsList-1_0_war (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/tvTutorial, service org.wildfly.data-source.tvTutorial] 
WFLYCTL0448: 2 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed"
16:10:56,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "NewPestsList-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "NewPestsList-1.0.war")
16:10:56,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.NewPestsList-1_0_war (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/tvTutorial, service org.wildfly.data-source.tvTutorial] 
WFLYCTL0448: 2 additional services are down due to their dependencies being missing or failed
16:11:01,096 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found NewPestsList-1.0.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called NewPestsList-1.0.war.dodeploy
16:11:01,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "NewPestsList-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "NewPestsList-1.0.war")
16:11:02,321 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for NewPestsList
16:11:02,415 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment NewPestsList-1.0.war
16:11:02,430 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'NewPestsList-1.0.war#NewPestsList'
16:11:02,431 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: NewPestsList
    ...]
16:11:02,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.2)
16:11:02,721 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 42.2)
16:11:02,721 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0003: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.postgresql.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.NewPestsList-1_0_war_org_postgresql_Driver_42_2 is already registered
16:11:02,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = NewPestsList-1.0.war
16:11:02,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = NewPestsList-1.0.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2
16:11:02,739 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/tvTutorial]
16:11:02,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'NewPestsList-1.0.war#NewPestsList'
16:11:02,748 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
16:11:02,755 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@74330d99
16:11:02,757 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Envers integration enabled? : true
16:11:02,970 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
16:11:02,970 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-2) MicroProfile: Metrics activated
16:11:03,146 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP02 for context '/NewPestsList-1.0'
16:11:04,491 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Running on PrimeFaces 7.0
16:11:04,502 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/NewPestsList-1.0' for server 'default-server'
16:11:04,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "NewPestsList-1.0.war" (runtime-name : "NewPestsList-1.0.war")
16:11:04,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0185:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.data-source.reference-factory.tvTutorial (new available)
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.NewPestsList-1_0_war (new available)
      service org.wildfly.data-source.tvTutorial (new available)
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with this, but as I am new to programming I am not sure if I should add some more data, please let me know.

Edit: I updated my program with help of stdunbar and Will T.
Will have still to learn how to reinstall Wildfly.
Now I get these Warnings and Errors:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\david\wildfly-17.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0003: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.postgresql.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.NewPestsList-1_0_war_org_postgresql_Driver_42_2 is already registered
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "NewPestsList-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.tvTutorial"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"NewPestsList-1.0.war#tvTutorialPU\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.tvTutorial]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"NewPestsList-1.0.war#tvTutorialPU\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.tvTutorial]"
```

Edit #2:

It works after I wrote correct adress in
    `<jta-data-source>jdbc/tvTutorial</jta-data-source>`
Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

The diver must be added as a module, you can't reference your war deployment

This guide is for mysql, but the process is the same, just use the right names

https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/install-and-configure-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-jboss-wildfly-e751a3be60d3

Comment: Thank you for the response. I undeployed both driver and database and went by the instructions. There is still warning:

```WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0003: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.postgresql.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.NewPestsList-1_0_war_org_postgresql_Driver_42_2 is already registered```

This driver was not there when I undeployed both things, but when I redeployed, it came back. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a datasource *and* a JDBC connection.  You really just want the datasource.  So rather than the manual steps you've taken to modify standalone.xml and install a module I recommend a far more standard approach that is less error prone.  You can script the entire process by just having a copy of the JDBC driver available.

Create a script that contains code like:

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml --std-out=echo

batch

# add the module
module add --name=org.postgres --resources=/path/to/postgresql-42.2.8.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

# add the driver
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgres",driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)

# add the datasource
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=tvTutorial/:add(connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tvTutorial,driver-name=postgres,jndi-name=java:/jdbc/tvTutorial,user-name=user,password=password)

run-batch
```

Then run this with:

```
$WILDFLY_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=the_file_name.cli
```

(note that $WILDFLY_HOME is likely not set.  It is just the directory in which you have Wildfly installed)

That assumes that your serve is not currently running.  If it is running then remove the first two lines and the last line.

Your `persistence.xml` file is now super simple as the configuration is all in `standalone.xml` via the datasource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="tvTutorialPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/tvTutorial</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What this gives you is a repeatable process.  You now don't have to modify the `standalone.xml` file by hand and if you upgrade I've used this same script on Wildfly 8.x to 18.x.

I would start with a fresh install of Wildfly as you don't know what all has been damaged.

Comment: ¨Thank you for your help. Now I have updated errors and warnings

Comment: Just one (maybe stupid) question: I want also to search for and add data to database. For that I probably need connection to database? I don't know where to write that

Comment: @Freeky - now it gets fun.  I found a [pretty simple tutorial](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/12/jpa-crud-example/) that should get you started.  Note that you already have your `persistence.xml` correct so ignore that section.  JPA is a very powerful tool but there is a bit of an initial learning curve.  If you're ok with this answer I'd appreciate an upvote and mark as accepted.  Then, if you get stuck on JPA I'd open a new question.